# RabbitMQ suddenly does not receive messages from Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've been moving my dev-environment from Linux to Mac and suddenly I'm facing weird RabbitMQ behavior.

I had Ubuntu box, on which RabbitMQ 2.8.7-1 runned and I did dev stuff on the same box. I've been running my testcode (provided below) and Rabbit were happy to receive all messages.

```
// using spring-rabbit 1.1.1.RELEASE
AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate = (AmqpTemplate) context.getBean("amqpTemplate");
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("bar.queue", "Foo message");
```

Now I moved to Mac box (host A), in which I'm running VirtualBox with Linux (host B), on which runs RabbitMQ with the same configuration as on previous Linux box. I'm running my dev environment on Mac, which calls Rabbit inside VM :). But nothing came, so I used Wireshark to track down communication, which seems ok:

```
. . . .
B > A: Connection.Start
A > B: Connection.Start-Ok
B > A: Connection.Tune
A > B: Connection.Tune-Ok
A > B: Connection.Open
B > A: Connection.Open-Ok
A > B: Channel.Open
B > A: Channel.Open-Ok
A > B: Basic.Publish (bar.queue)
A > B: Content-Header (text/plain)
A > B: Content-Body (Foo message)
A > B: Channel.Close (200-OK)
B > A: [[TCP ACK for Channel.Close]]
. . . .
```

So it looks like message had been received, but maybe not processed by broker? Log on client side also tells me that message was published.

```
17:09:37.450 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'amqpTemplate'
17:09:37.576 [main] DEBUG o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@hostB:5672/,1)
17:09:37.611 [main] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@hostB:5672/,1)
17:09:37.612 [main] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Publishing message on exchange [], routingKey = [bar.queue]
```

I have absolutely no idea where to start looking after problem, why it was working before and not now, where can be problem?

edit:
OK, I tried to implement simple sender from RabbitMQ tutorial and it looks like it hangs on close(), because application still runs and code after close() is not reached.

```
channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, messageBodyBytes);
channel.close();
// this is never reached and app still running :-o
conn.close();
```

Comment: I installed RabbitMQ on Mac and it's able to receive messages. So I omit host B for now and use only host A. But I still'd like to resolve that case.

Answer (score 1):

How much free disk space do you have on your VirtualBox?

This looks very similar to my problem. I was calling BasicPublish method from C# under Windows 7 x64. RabbitMQ installed on the same machine. The code was hanging at the same line as yours.  When I put BasicPublish between TxSelect and TxCommit methods, then the program was hanging at TxCommit.

After some time I realized that my HDD was almost full (can't really remember but around 200MB of free space). I freed some space and that helped.

Comment: There is 570MB, so maybe this may be my problem. I'm in another context now, so unable to try it right now. But I let you know, thanks...